# Importing .gdb file in desktop ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, file-geodatabase

When I am importing .gdb file in QGIS, I cannot see the all years data.

I am trying to import the .gdb folder in ArcMap using the following step:

`Add data -> connect to folder -> folder.gdb`

But I cannot add and open the folder. Can anyone tell me which step I am missing?

Comment: File geodatabase is an Esri file format. If ArcGIS can't read it, the data folder is corrupt.

Comment: Note that file geodatabase is *not* a single file. It is a folder (directory) with a ".gdb" suffix containing more than a score of files.  If you have a zipfile and haven't  disabled "hide suffixes of known formats", you should  do that before extracting to a folder.

Comment: thanks. How can I do "hide suffixes of known formats"?

Comment: Well, a [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=hide+suffixes+of+known+formats) would be a way to start.

Comment: either a corrupt file geodatabase or a raster geodatabase with imagery.

Comment: May not be corrupt. You can't "Add data -> connect to folder -> folder.gdb" because it's not a "folder" to ArcGIS, it's a file geodatabase.  Use "Add data" and just browse to the filegeodatabase.gdb. If you can't browse and do need to "connect to folder", connect to a folder (not the .gdb) at a level above the geodatabase.

Comment: You should connect to the folder where your geodatabase is located, but not to the geodatabase itself.  user2856 gave a right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected the .gdb folder to a generic folder (not .gdb) and it's working perfect.